# How to give proof for Q ∧ R with the premisse ¬(¬¬¬P ∨ P)?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I'm trying to use Fitch to get to an answer, but I'm really confused right now. Can someone help?

Comment: To be able to prove a statement consisting *entirely* of terms not contained in any of the premises , then either: the statement will be a tautology, or the premises will contain a contradiction .

Comment: A comment about the answers: As i understand the operation of ex false quodlibet, the falsity of the premise here would not exactly prove that "Q and R" is true. Rather, because anything can follow from the false premise, "Q and R" is simply one among a limitless set of possible conclusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Here is a proof with *Natural Deduction* :

1)  **¬(¬¬¬P ∨ P)** --- assumed

2) **¬P ∨ P** --- *Law of Excluded Middle* (is a tautology)

3) **P** --- assumed [a]

4) **¬¬¬P ∨ P** --- from 3) by ∨-introduction

5) **¬P** --- assumed [b]

6) **¬¬¬P** --- from 5) by *Double Negation* : **φ ⊢ ¬¬φ**

7) **¬¬¬P ∨ P** --- from 6) by ∨-introduction

Now, from 3)-4) and 5)-7) we have derived  **¬¬¬P ∨ P** from both assumptions : **P** and **¬P**. Using ∨-elimination (*proof by cases*) from 2) we conclude with :

8) **¬¬¬P ∨ P** --- discharging assumptions [a] and [b]

Now 8) contradicts 1); thus, from *Ex Falso Quodlibet* : **φ, ¬φ ⊢ ψ** we conclude with :

> 9) **Q ∧ R**.

Thus, from 1)-9) we have :

> > **¬(¬¬¬P ∨ P) ⊢ Q ∧ R**

---

*Note*

We can prove *LEM* :  **¬φ ∨ φ** using the "other half" of *DN* : **¬¬φ ⊢ φ**.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just going to give you the general way to solve these kinds of problems, as this looks like a homework question.

Since there are no common variables between the expression "Q ∧ R" and "¬(¬¬¬P ∨ P)", you can only proof the causality by proving that the latter is necessarily false. From something untrue anything follows. This is called [*ex falso (sequitur) quodlibet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

Answer (score 1):

In the following proof, I've used *ex falso* not to produce directly the conclusion, but only to eliminate the premise previously turned into a disjunct ( by v intro). The conclusion follows as the only disjunct that remains ( through disjunctive syllogism).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer agrees with [Keelan's observation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/18249/29944) that since there is no common variable between the conclusion and the premises one needs to show that '¬(¬¬¬P ∨ P)' is a contradiction.  This can be shown using a truth table as follows:

[image]

One can conclude anything from that, in particular, 'Q ∧ R', as this truth table shows:

[image]

This is not the desired solution since the solution is supposed to use Fitch-style natural deduction. The following proof is similar to the one [Mauro ALLEGRANZA provided](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/18242/29944). The only difference is it starts with '¬¬P v ¬¬¬P' to use the law of excluded middle:

[image]

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Michael Rieppel. Truth Table Generator. https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html